# How to register click event of button in GridView header with ajax UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have an UpdatePanel containing a GridView which contains a button in the HeaderTemplate of a TemplateField.  I want to add this button's click event to the UpdatePanel's trigger collection but this doesn't seem to work as I get an error message saying that a control with the specified ID could not be found.

I thought of programmatically adding to the UpdatePanel's trigger collection on page load but this doesn't seem to be possible.

Is there a work-around to this problem? I'd ideally like to keep my button within the header of the GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this by accessing the ScriptManager on the page instead of the UpdatePanel itself.  I did this inside the Page_Load method.  My code is as follows:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    Button button = GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("myHeaderButton") as Button;
    if (button != null)
        scriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(button);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the VB code.  I don't have the ability to test this (and there is a chance that it is way off, and there is probably a better way to do it), but it should point you in the right direction:

```
Dim g As GridView = UpdatePanel1.FindControl(nameofgridview)
Dim Button As Button = g.HeaderRow.FindControl(nameofbutton)
Dim u As UpdatePanel = Page.FindControl(panelID)
Dim trigger As UpdatePanelControlTrigger
trigger.ControlID = Button
u.Triggers.Add(trigger)
```

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work as UpdatePanelControlTrigger is an abstract class and can't actually be instantiated.